# Simple array access and manipulation methods

Tags: php, arrays

Hy, I designed an array, and I need some help because I've got aaaloot of headaches. Can anyone give me a simple idea how to work with this in a simple way?

Most of the errors when I try to add some values in my array are array offset error.

**My array:**

```
$info = array
(
    "id" => "",
    "city" => "",
    "university" => array
    (
        "name"    => "",
        "address"  => "",
        "phone"   => "",
            "fax"     => "",
        "email"   => "",
        "website" => "",
        "type"    => "",
        "faculty" => array
        (
            "name"    => "",
            "adress"  => "",
            "phone"   => "",
            "fax"     => "",
            "email"   => "",
            "website" => "",
            "type"    => "",
        )
    )
);
```

**CODE:**

```
<?php
// HTML DOM PARSER LIBRARY
include('hdp.php');

//error_reporting(false);

/*
 * Returns an array with field associative name and
 * extracted value, using a specified delimiter.
 */

function extractField($str, $delim)
{
        $val = '';
    // All possible fields
    $posFlds = array
    (
        'Adresa'  => 'address',
            'Telefon' => 'phone',
        'Fax'     => 'fax',
        'Email'   => 'email',
        'Website' => 'website',
        'Tip'     => 'type'
    );

    foreach($posFlds as $fldName => $assocName)
    {
        if(strstr($str,$fldName))
        {
            $val = @explode($delim,$str);
            if (!$val[1])
            {
                    print 'Delimiter `'.$delim.'` not found!';
                    return false;
                }
                return array($assocName, $val[1]);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // DB->Table query structure
    $info = array
    (
    "id" => "",
    "city" => "",
    "university" => array
    (
        "name"    => "",
        "address"  => "",
            "phone"   => "",
        "fax"     => "",
        "email"   => "",
        "website" => "",
        "type"    => "",
        "faculty" => array
        (
            "name"    => "",
            "adress"  => "",
            "phone"   => "",
            "fax"     => "",
            "email"   => "",
            "website" => "",
            "type"    => "",
        )
    )
);

// City identifier
$cityid = 0;

// Rows, columns and deep identifiers
$i = 0; $j = 0; $k = 0;

// Base, secondary and third crawl url
$baseUrl = 'XXX';
$secondaryUrl = ''; $thirdUrl ='';

// Html contents without stripped tags (as is)
$htmlCu = file_get_html($baseUrl);
$htmltUn = ''; $htmltFa = '';

// Selectors for third level deep check
$selectCu = $htmlCu->find('td[width="100%"] table td');
$selectUn = ''; $selectFa ='';

// Text formats (raw and cleaned)
$rtext =''; $ftext = '';

// Contoare
$a=0; $b=0; $c=0;

// Select each row from parent td -> child table -> child td
foreach($selectCu as $row)
{
    // Skip first row result
    if($i != 0)
    {
        $rtext = $row->plaintext;
        $ftext = trim($rtext,'&nbsp;&bull; ');
        if($ftext != '-')
        {
            // If string contains a dot it is a city
            if(strstr($rtext, '&bull;'))
            {
                print "CITY = ".$ftext."<br>";
                $cityid++;
                $info[$a]["city"] = $ftext;
            }
            // If string is not a city, then is a university
            else
            {
                $info[$a]["city"][$b]['university']['name'] = $ftext;
                echo "<b>----ID [".$i."]; NAME:</b> ".$ftext."<br>";
                $secondaryUrl = $row->find('a',0)->href;
                $htmlUn = file_get_html($secondaryUrl);
                $selectUn = $htmlUn->find('td[width="100%"] table tr');
                foreach($selectUn as $col)
                {
                    // Skip first row result
                    if($j != 0)
                    {
                        $rtext = $col->plaintext;
                        $ftext = trim($rtext,'&nbsp;&bull; ');
                        echo "--------ID[".$j."] NAME: <b>".$ftext."</b>; TYPE: ".gettype($col)."<br>";
                        // key 0 -> associative name; key 1 -> value
                        $field = extractField($ftext,': ');
                        if($field)
                        {
                            echo "--------<b>Field name:</b> ".$field[0]."<b>, value:</b> ".$field[1]."<br>";
                        }
                        /////////////////////////////TESTTTTTT ZONEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE/////////////////////////////
                        // If string contains a dot it is a faculty
                        if(strstr($rtext, '&bull;'))
                        {
                            $thirdUrl = $col->find('a',0)->href;

                            $htmlFa = file_get_html($thirdUrl);
                            $selectFa = $htmlFa->find('td[width="100%"] table tr');
                            foreach($selectFa as $deep)
                            {
                                $rtext = $deep->plaintext;
                                $ftext = trim($rtext,'&nbsp;&bull; ');
                                //echo "------------id[".$k."] <-> <b>".$ftext."</b> <-> ".gettype($deep)."<br>";
                                    $field = extractField($ftext,': ');
                                if($field)
                                {
                                    echo "------------<b>Field name:</b> ".$field[0]."<b>, value:</b> ".$field[1]."<br>";
                                }
                                $k++;
                            }
                            echo "<br><br>";
                        }
                    }
                    $j++;
                }
                echo "<br><br>";
            }
        }
    }
    $i++;
    if($cityid == 2) break;
}
print "<h1>".($i-1)."</h1>";

print_r($info);
```

Comment: How are you accessing your array and what are the errors you get? Please be more specific.

Comment: can you add the code which you tried...

Comment: Many many errors "Cannot use string offset as an array in"

Comment: I will edit post now with te full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final and working code, if anyone fiind this usefull:

```
// HTML DOM PARSER LIBRARY
include('hdp.php');
error_reporting(true);

// Session to know what last city was
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['LAST']) $_SESSION['LAST'] = NULL;

/*
 * Returns an array with field associative name and
 * extracted value, using a specified delimiter.
 */

function extractField($str, $delim)
{
    $val = '';
    // All possible fields
    $posFlds = Array
    (
        'Adresa'  => 'address',
        'Telefon' => 'phone',
        'Fax'     => 'fax',
        'Email'   => 'email',
        'Website' => 'website',
        'Tip'     => 'type'
    );

    foreach($posFlds as $fldName => $assocName)
    {
        if(strstr($str,$fldName))
        {
            $val = @explode($delim,$str);
            if (!$val[1])
            {
                print 'Delimiter `'.$delim.'` not found!';
                return false;
            }
            return array($assocName, $val[1]);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Trying to connect to local server
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","educatie") or die("Could not connect to MySQL server!");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// DB->Table Query structure
$info = Array
(
    "city" => Array
    (
        "name"       => "",
        "university" => Array
        (
            "name"    => "",
            "address" => "",
            "phone"   => "",
            "fax"     => "",
            "email"   => "",
            "website" => "",
            "type"    => "",
            "faculty" => Array
            (
                "name"    => "",
                "adress"  => "",
                "phone"   => "",
                "fax"     => "",
                "email"   => "",
                "website" => "",
                "type"    => "",
            )
        ),
    )
);

// City identifier
$cityid = 0;

// Rows, columns and deep identifiers
$i = 0; $j = 0; $k = 0;

// Base, secondary and third crawl url
$baseUrl = 'http://infoportal.rtv.net/informatii_universitati.html';
$secondaryUrl = ''; $thirdUrl ='';

// Html contents without stripped tags (as is)
$htmlCu = file_get_html($baseUrl);
$htmltUn = ''; $htmltFa = '';

// Selectors for third level deep check
$selectCu = $htmlCu->find('td[width="100%"] table td');
$selectUn = ''; $selectFa ='';

// Text formats (raw and cleaned)
$rtext =''; $ftext = '';

// Ignore tokens
$banned = array("&nbsp;","&bull;","&quot;","  ");

// Counters A, B and C
$a=0; $b=0; $c=0;

// Temporary variables
$tmpVar = '';

// Select each row from parent td -> child table -> child td
foreach($selectCu as $row)
{
    // Skip first row result
    if($i != 0)
    {
        $rtext = $row->plaintext;
        $ftext = trim($rtext,'&nbsp;&bull; ');
        if($ftext != '-')
        {
            // If string contains a dot it is a city
            if(strstr($rtext, '&bull;'))
            {
                if(($_SESSION['LAST'] !== $ftext) && ($_SESSION['LAST'] !== NULL)) continue;
                print "<h1>-> Oras: ".$ftext."</h1><br>";
                echo "SESSION:".$_SESSION['LAST']."|<br />";
                $tmpVar = $ftext;
            }
            // If string is not a city, then is a university
            else
            {
                $a--;
                $info[$a]['city']['name'] = $tmpVar;
                $info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['name'] = $ftext;
                $secondaryUrl = $row->find('a',0)->href;
                $htmlUn = file_get_html($secondaryUrl);
                $selectUn = $htmlUn->find('td[width="100%"] table tr');
                foreach($selectUn as $col)
                {
                    // Skip first row result
                    if($j != 0)
                    {
                        $rtext = $col->plaintext;
                        $ftext = trim($rtext,'&nbsp;&bull; ');
                        // key 0 -> associative name; key 1 -> value
                        $field = extractField($ftext,': ');
                        if($field)
                        {
                            if(strstr($field[1],'de stat'))
                                $info[$a]['city']['university'][$b][$field[0]] = 'de stat';
                            else
                                $info[$a]['city']['university'][$b][$field[0]] = $field[1];
                        }
                        /////////////////////////////TESTTTTTT ZONEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE/////////////////////////////
                        // If string contains a dot it is a faculty
                        if(strstr($rtext, '&bull;'))
                        {
                            $tempVar = trim(str_replace($banned,'',$ftext),' ');
                            $thirdUrl = $col->find('a',0)->href;

                            $htmlFa = file_get_html($thirdUrl);
                            $selectFa = $htmlFa->find('td[width="100%"] table tr');
                            foreach($selectFa as $deep)
                            {
                                $rtext = $deep->plaintext;
                                $ftext = trim($rtext,'&nbsp;&bull; ');
                                $info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['faculty'][$c]['name'] = $tempVar;
                                $field = extractField($ftext,': ');
                                if($field)
                                {
                                    if($field[0]=='website')
                                    {
                                        $info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['faculty'][$c][$field[0]] = $deep->find('a',0)->href;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['faculty'][$c][$field[0]]  = $field[1];
                                    }
                                }                                   
                                $k++;
                            }
                            $facName = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['faculty'][$c]['name'];
                            $facAddr = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['faculty'][$c]['address'];
                            $facPhone = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['faculty'][$c]['phone'];
                            $facFax = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['faculty'][$c]['fax'];
                            $facEmail = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['faculty'][$c]['email'];
                            $facWeb = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['faculty'][$c]['website'];
                            $facTax = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['faculty'][$c]['type'];

                            echo "<b>ID UNIVERSITATE:</b> ".$a."<br />";
                            echo "<b>Nume facultate:</b> ".$facName."<br />";
                            echo "<b>Adresa:</b> ".$facAddr."<br />";
                            echo "<b>Telefon:</b> ".$facPhone."<br />";
                            echo "<b>Fax:</b> ".$facFax."<br />";
                            echo "<b>Email:</b> ".$facEmail."<br />";
                            echo "<b>Pagina web:</b> ".$facWeb."<br />";
                            echo "<b>Tip taxa:</b> ".$facTax."<br /><br />";
                            mysqli_query($conn,"
                                INSERT INTO faculty
                                VALUES ('$a','$facName','$facAddr','$facPhone','$facFax','$facEmail','$facWeb','$facTax')
                            ");
                            $c++;
                        }
                    }
                    $j++;
                }
                $univCity = @$info[$a]['city']['name'];
                $univName = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['name'];
                $univAddr = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['address'];
                $univPhone = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['phone'];
                $univFax = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['fax'];
                $univEmail = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['email'];
                $univWeb = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['website'];
                $univTax = @$info[$a]['city']['university'][$b]['type'];

                echo "<b>ID UNIVERSITATE:</b> ".$a."<br />";
                echo "<b>Oras:</b> ".$univCity."<br />";
                echo "<b>Nume universitate:</b> ".$univName."<br />";
                echo "<b>Adresa:</b> ".$univAddr."<br />";
                echo "<b>Telefon:</b> ".$univPhone."<br />";
                echo "<b>Fax:</b> ".$univFax."<br />";
                echo "<b>Email:</b> ".$univEmail."<br />";
                echo "<b>Pagina web:</b> ".$univWeb."<br />";
                echo "<b>Tip taxa:</b> ".$univTax."<br />";
                mysqli_query($conn,"
                    INSERT INTO university
                    VALUES ('$a','$univCity','$univName','$univAddr','$univPhone','$univFax','$univEmail','$univWeb','$univTax')
                ");
                $b++;
                echo "<br><br>";
            }
            $a++;
        }
    }
    // SESSION IT, IF THIS JOB IS COMPLETE
    if($tmpVar) $_SESSION['LAST'] = $tmpVar;
    $i++;
}
print "<h1>".($i-1)."</h1>";
print_r($info);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the array the wrong way in those calls:

```
$info[$a]["city"] = $ftext;
$info[$a]["city"][$b]['university']['name'] = $ftext;
```

Correct would be:

```
$info["city"] = $ftext;
$info["city"]['university']['name'] = $ftext;
```

It seems you want to handle multiple `$info`-arrays. For this you have to create an array of those info-arrays.

Comment: Yes, but $info is an array how is posible to access without an key index? like $info['university']['name'] = "Name";

Comment: @LXSoft You are accessing it by the key e.g. `city`.

Comment: To be honest I think want you are trying to do is too complex for your current knowledge. Start with a simple example and learn how to create and handle an array. Then try it with a loop. When you managed to do this get back to your current script.

Comment: Yes but if I want this: info[0] info[1] i want a lot of info array with key numbers.

Comment: @LXSoft btw have you realized that `$a` is always `0`? There is no increment.

Comment: I finish it works perfectly, with selectors like: $info[$a]['city'][$b]['university'][$c]['faculty'][$field[0]]  = $field[1];